# Extract rows based on patterns in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, design-patterns

I am learning Python and was working on one of the dataset like this:

```
**Col1**                                 **Col2**      **Col3**      **Col4**  
dog                                        Z             st02          0
dog,cat                                    Z             st02          1
dog,bat,cat                                Z             st02          2
bat,cat,elephant                           Y             st02          2
dog,bat,cat,elephant                       Y             st02          3
tiger                                      Z             st01          0
lion,leopard,cheetah                       Z             st01          2
tiger,lion,leopard,cheetah                 Z             st01          3
dog,tiger,cheetah                          Y             st01          2
dog,tiger,leopard,cheetah                  Y             st01          3
eagle,jaguar,Kangaroo,zebra                Z             st02          3
cheetah,eagle,jaguar,Kangaroo,zebra        Z             st02          4
```

The expected output is:

```
**Col1**                                 **Col2**       **Col3**      **Col4**
dog,bat,cat                                Z              st02          2
dog,bat,cat,elephant                       Y              st02          3
tiger,lion,leopard,cheetah                 Z              st01          3
dog,tiger,leopard,cheetah                  Y              st01          3
cheetah,eagle,jaguar,Kangaroo,zebra        Z              st02          4
```

In order to extract the above rows as output, I tried tracing the patterns and using the below logic:

```
data = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")
data['Col4'] = data['Col1'].str.count(',')
v1 = []
v2 = []
v1.append(0)
v2.append(0)
for i in range(0,data.shape[0]-1):
    x = data['Col_2'][i]
    y = data['Col_2'][i+1]
    t1 = data['Col_3'][i]
    t2 = data['Col_3'][i+1]
    g1 = (x == y) & (t1==t2)
    d1 = data['Col_1'][i]
    d2 = data['Col_1'][i+1]
    c1 = data['Col_4'][i]
    c2 = data['Col_4'][i+1]
    flag = 0
    if(all(x in d2 for x in d1)):
      flag = 1
    g2 = (flag == 1)&(c2>c1)
    v1.append(g1)
    v2.append(g2)
    data['new_cond1'] = v1   
    data['new_cond2'] = v2   
    data['Final_flag'] = (data['new_cond1']==True)&(data['new_cond2']==True) 
    data_output = data[data['Final_flag']==True]
```

But I didn't end up getting the expected output, rather few additional rows are also present in output. Could someone please help me extracting the rows mentioned in expected output.

### Update 2:

When I add the following to the above dataframe:

```
**Col1**                                 **Col2**      **Col3**      **Col4**  
  pigeon                                   Z             st01          0
  pigeon,parrot                            Z             st01          1
  dove,parrot                              Z             st01          1
  pigeon,parrot                            Z             st01          1
  pigeon,parrot,dove                       Z             st01          2
```

The outcome expected would also include:

```
pigeon,parrot,dove                         Z             st01          2
```

Though the max(Col4) of "pigeon,parrot,dove" row is not greater than the maximum count(Col4) within the consecutive group, it is included as part of output.
I think this is because the category of Col1 also matters. That is, since the newly added row has different category of words "pigeon,parrot,dove".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If want rows by maximal `,` of `Col1` per consecutive groups by `Col2` and `Col3` use:

```
g = df[['Col2','Col3']].ne(df[['Col2','Col3']].shift()).any(1).cumsum()
df1 = df.loc[df.groupby(g)['Col4'].idxmax()]
print (df1)
                                   Col1 Col2  Col3  Col4
2                           dog,bat,cat    Z  st02     2
4                  dog,bat,cat,elephant    Y  st02     3
7            tiger,lion,leopard,cheetah    Z  st01     3
9             dog,tiger,leopard,cheetah    Y  st01     3
11  cheetah,eagle,jaguar,Kangaroo,zebra    Z  st02     4
```

EDIT:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['dog', 'dog,cat', 'dog,bat,cat', 'bat,cat,elephant', 'dog,bat,cat,elephant', 'tiger', 'lion,leopard,cheetah', 'tiger,lion,leopard,cheetah', 'dog,tiger,cheetah', 'dog,tiger,leopard,cheetah', 'eagle,jaguar,Kangaroo,zebra', 'cheetah,eagle,jaguar,Kangaroo,zebra', 'pigeon', 'pigeon,parrot', 'dove,parrot', 'pigeon,parrot', 'pigeon,parrot,dove'], 'Col2': ['Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Y', 'Y', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Y', 'Y', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z'], 'Col3': ['st02', 'st02', 'st02', 'st02', 'st02', 'st01', 'st01', 'st01', 'st01', 'st01', 'st02', 'st02', 'st01', 'st01', 'st01', 'st01', 'st01'], 'Col4': [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2]})
```

---

```
print (df)
                                   Col1 Col2  Col3  Col4
0                                   dog    Z  st02     0 <group1
1                               dog,cat    Z  st02     1
2                           dog,bat,cat    Z  st02     2

3                      bat,cat,elephant    Y  st02     2 <group2
4                  dog,bat,cat,elephant    Y  st02     3

5                                 tiger    Z  st01     0 <group3
6                  lion,leopard,cheetah    Z  st01     2
7            tiger,lion,leopard,cheetah    Z  st01     3

8                     dog,tiger,cheetah    Y  st01     2 <group4
9             dog,tiger,leopard,cheetah    Y  st01     3

10          eagle,jaguar,Kangaroo,zebra    Z  st02     3 <group5
11  cheetah,eagle,jaguar,Kangaroo,zebra    Z  st02     4

12                               pigeon    Z  st01     0 <group6
13                        pigeon,parrot    Z  st01     1
14                          dove,parrot    Z  st01     1
15                        pigeon,parrot    Z  st01     1
16                   pigeon,parrot,dove    Z  st01     2
```

---

```
g = df[['Col2','Col3']].ne(df[['Col2','Col3']].shift()).any(1).cumsum()
df1 = df.loc[df.groupby(g)['Col4'].idxmax()]
print (df1)
                                   Col1 Col2  Col3  Col4
2                           dog,bat,cat    Z  st02     2
4                  dog,bat,cat,elephant    Y  st02     3
7            tiger,lion,leopard,cheetah    Z  st01     3
9             dog,tiger,leopard,cheetah    Y  st01     3
11  cheetah,eagle,jaguar,Kangaroo,zebra    Z  st02     4
16                   pigeon,parrot,dove    Z  st01     2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @jezrael. Just have a small doubt please, if it's extracting based on maximal  of Col1, per groups by Col2 and Col3, there are 2 rows in the expected output for a particular Col2 value "Z" and Col3 value "st02". Example is **row no. 2** and **row no.11**. So are we extracting the rows based on Col1 as well? Because "dog,bat,cat" from **row no. 2** with max(comma) value as "2" is also present in expected output when compared with "cheetah,eagle,jaguar,Kangaroo,zebra" from **row no.11** with max(comma) value as "4". Both belong to the same group.

Comment: @pc_pyr - Difference is `per consecutive groups` - it means I distingush same groups, because not consecutive. If need same, use `df1 = df.loc[df.groupby(['Col2','Col3'])['Col4'].idxmax()]`

Comment: when I tried with the approach used earlier, it's not fetching the row with **"pigeon,parrot,dove"**. Should we take the category of Col1 also into consideration. Since when new category of words are appended and if their count(comma)<max, then they are not being included in the group. So, the objective might be to include max(comma) with respect to each category of unique words present in Col1. @jezrael

Comment: @pc_pyr - Because there is only one row for maximal `col4` per groups `col2, col3`

Comment: I am using the "per consecutive group" approach for the newly appended rows also @jezrael. But the output doesn't seem to include **"pigeon,parrot,dove"** row

Comment: @pc_pyr hmmm, for me working nice. Include `pigeon,parrot,dove`

Comment: Sure @jezrael, I have appended `pigeon,parrot,dove` in the previous dataset, not creating a new dataset. Did you get them in the appended or new dataframe

Comment: @pc_pyr - ya, if new rows are added to original data sample it working nice, for you not?

Comment: Yes @jazrael, it's working nice, all the expected rows are being picked except the fact that `pigeon,parrot,dove` row is not included in output

Comment: Need we change the logic in order to include `pigeon,parrot,dove` in output?

Comment: @pc_pyr - Added sample data to answer, for me working nice. So if for you not, some data related problem.

Comment: So I just figured out that when I append the sample data to existing dataset at the end, then it's working good. But when those `Update-2` rows are added somewhere in between the existing dataset (For eg., I added them after 7th row), then I don't get `pigeon,parrot,dove`. Does it have any influence on the order of data ? @jezrael

Comment: @pc_pyr - yes, sure. It depends by groups with`col2` and `col3`, I edit answer for show groups.

Comment: @jazrael, Is there a way I can get a constant output without any influence on the order of data?

Comment: @pc_pyr - Not understand. Because  my solution working with groups, so it depends of groups, but if create new column for distingush this new rows, it is possible.

Comment: So in order to distinguish each row, could you please guide me on how to check if one row is a subset of another row as it is "string of strings". This is because I didn't want the output to change with respect to order of data/groups.

Comment: @pc_pyr - I think the best is create new question for this.